# What is the difference between %h and %b in strftime

Tags: c, strftime

I was reading the man page for [`strftime`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) and I found this:

> `%b`     The  abbreviated  month  name  according  to the current locale. (Calculated from `tm_mon`.)
>
> *[...]*
>
> `%h`     Equivalent to `%b`.  (SU)

Are both exactly the same or is there any difference? Is there a special case where one should be preferred over the other?

Comment: As "`"%h"` is equivalent to `"%b"`. [tm_mon]", (h in terms of b), it implies to me that `"%b"` is preferred.  `H` is nothing like `h`, while `B` relates to `b`.

Comment: Read the "CONFORMING TO" section in the man page. It tells you what the code in the brackets, e.g. `(SU)`, means which is of relevance to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent in *behaviour*. However, `%h` was standardized in the **Single Unix Specification** (SU). It is an addition that [did not exist in C89](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.12.3.5).

There is practically never a case where `%h` would work but `%b` would not - it would mean you're targeting a Unix system that supports `%h` but does not support `%b` with an implementation that conforms to neither the 31-year-old standard revision, nor any of its amendments. The opposite is *still* (unfortunately) more likely.

TL;DR: always use `%b` instead of `%h`.

Answer (score 5):

They are identical.

Over the decades, there have been a number of different Unix implementations, and a number of different functions which convert between string representations and dates. Some of these functions used `%b` for the abbreviated month and some of them used `%h`. Over time, all of the legacy interfaces except `strftime` were deprecated, and the different format codes were merged, not only with the different `strftime` equivalents but also with the related `strptime` function (which parses strings to produce a date) and the command-line `date` utilities. (There is still a lot of variance between command line options to `date`, but the core formatting codes, at least, are interoperable.) The result was that a number of format codes have two different spellings.

Most modern programs use `%b`, and you're unlikely to find a system which only supports `%h`, at least outside of a museum. But both `%b` and `%h` are mandated by Posix, with identical meanings, and there's nothing which suggests that `%h` is facing deprecation. So which one you use is your choice.